# In NextJS, how to build when referencing external npm package that contains SVGs?

Tags: svg, webpack, babeljs, next.js

My nextjs project (let's call it TheHost) **references another npm package** (let's call it ThePackage).

SVGs load fine when defined within TheHost, but importing ThePackage fails because next tries to interpret the svg as javascript... so I get the following error when doing a `next build`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

To re-iterate, SVGs work fine when referencing an svg defined in TheHost itself. The problem seems to be importing npm packages that contain SVGs.

It doesn't matter if I import a component from ThePackage that uses an SVG or not, just the fact that somewhere in the npm package it contains an "import xxx from '../path/to/svg' is enough to break `next build`.

For what it's worth, the ThePackage's transpiled javascript reads the svg as follows:

```
var _mysvg = require("../path/to/the-svg.svg");
```

## Lots of details:

The next build stack trace is:

```
> Using external babel configuration
> Location: "/Users/w/dev/TheHost/.babelrc"
Creating an optimized production build

Compiled successfully.

> Build error occurred
/Users/w/dev/TheHost/node_modules/ThePackage/build/assets/card_background.svg:1
<svg viewBox="0 0 860 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/w/dev/TheHost/node_modules/TheProject/build/card/style.js:14:47)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
Automatically optimizing pages .%
```

The .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

The next.config.js file:

```
const withSourceMaps = require("@zeit/next-source-maps");
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages(
  withSourceMaps({
    env: { *** redacted *** },
    publicRuntimeConfig: { *** redacted *** },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      if (!options.isServer) {
        config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
      }
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });
      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

The nextjs svgr package versions are as follows:

```
"next": "^9.2.1",
"next-images": "^1.3.0",
"@svgr/webpack": "^5.1.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
"babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
```

ThePackage is built with the following output configuration (webpack):

```
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: buildFolder,
    filename: 'ThePackage.js',
    library: 'ThePackage',
    libraryTarget: 'umd', /* Note: umd */
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
```

Comment: Why do you use `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` && `@svgr/webpack`?

Comment: @felixmosh, the babel-inline plugin was an attempt to solve the issue, hoping it would inline the SVGs from thePackage. Didn't seem to make a difference though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NextJS ignores `node_modules` by default so you'd need to specifically allow your config to be able to transpile your package. Fortunately, someone has already created a NextJS plugin to allow this: https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules

I'd also suggest using [Next Compose Plugins](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins) to neaten up the config. In the end, your next.config.js will look something like this:

```
const withSourceMaps = require("@zeit/next-source-maps");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['ThePackage']);

module.exports = withPlugins([
    withTM,
    [
        withImages,
        {
            exclude: /\.svg$/
        }
    ],
    withSourceMaps
],
{
    env: { *** redacted *** },
    publicRuntimeConfig: { *** redacted *** },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      if (!options.isServer) {
        config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
      }
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });
      return config;
    }
});
```

I've also excluded SVGs from being processed by `withImages`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm not sure why. I'm still getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error